# I've misplaced one of my car components, can I get it back?

Tags: my-summer-car

I've been playing My Summer Car lately and it's been a struggle. Moreso than anything else, the sheer number of car parts to find, recover, maintain, or purchase has been extreme.

Recently, I was driving into town and had a cannister of gasoline in my vehicle. The jerry can must have glitched out of my trailer and perhaps flew into the stratosphere. Whatever the cause, I don't have it and thus can't fuel up my car.

What do I do now? The prospect of retracing my steps and looking for the gas can is somewhere between abysmal and impossible. Can I buy a new one or will a replacement spawn after being lost for a while?